# How can I pass a list of columns to select in pyspark dataframe?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have list column names.

```py
columns = ['home','house','office','work']
```

and I would like to pass that list values as columns name in "select" dataframe.

I have tried it...

```py
df_tables_full = df_tables_full.select('time_event','kind','schema','table',columns)
```

but I have received error below..

```py
TypeError: Invalid argument, not a string or column: ['home', 'house', 'office',
'work'] of type <class 'list'>. For column literals, use 'lit', 'array', 'struct' 
or 'create_map' function.
```

Can you have any ideia?
Thank you guys!

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Use `*` before  `columns` to unnest columns list and use in `.select`.

```
columns = ['home','house','office','work']

#select the list of columns
df_tables_full.select('time_event','kind','schema','table',*columns).show()

df_tables_full = df_tables_full.select('time_event','kind','schema','table',*columns)
```

Comment: This only works from Python 3.5 onwards?